# comparing two columns in two files

Tags: awk

I would like to compare two columns in two files.

Here's an example:

```
1   722603  0.08    0.0013  0.0035  0.02
1   793227  0.17    0   0   0.01
2   931508  0.52    0.95    0.93    0.92

1   722603  0.0348543
1   793227  0.130642
2   931508  0.275751
2   1025859 0.0739543
2   1237036 0.476705
```

This code compares the second columns of the two files:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]++; next} a[$2]' file 1 file 2
```

However, I want to print the common second column if the first column is also the same.  More specifically, if it finds 722603 in both files, it must check that the first column is also equal to 1 and then prints it.  If the number in second column is repeated, it is important that it gets printed more than once with different values of column 1.

I'd be very thankful if you could guide me through this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this? extended your codes a bit:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1 FS $2]++; next} a[$1 FS $2]' file1 file2
```