# Compare two files by two column matching

Tags: awk

I have two files with columns. I need to print the content of second file IF the **first** and the **second** columns of both files are equal. Ex:

```
file1

Name1 123 blabla
Name1 456 bla
Name3 777 s

file2

Name1 123 something more
Name2 456 some words
Name4 111 no

Desired output:

Name1 123 something more
```

I have written this code, but it only works for one column (the second in this case):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR == FNR {f[$2]; next;} $2 in f{print $0;}' file1 file2
```

I have found something related here: [comparing two columns in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265909/comparing-two-columns-in-two-files) , but I'm not able to find the correct way. I tried this but is not working..:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR == FNR {f[$1 FS $2]; next;} if($1 in f && $2 in f){print $0;}'
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1, $2]++; next } a[$1, $2]' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Name1 123 something more
```

- `[$1, $2]` is different from`[$1 "," $2]`. Somehow an implementation of Awk makes it sure that `$1, $2` would not match a literal string.

Comment: It works nice. Thanks. A little question, only curiosity, do you know why my code is not working?

Comment: For your second attempt you weren't assigning a value to `f[$1 FS $2]`. And that you were separately doing `in`s with those two values: `$1 in f && $2 in f`. Certainly there has never been `f[$1]` and `f[$2]`. On your version it could have been `f[$1 FS $2]++` ... `if ($1 FS $2 in f`)`